# co-occurencie words in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new with scala and I have some issues trying to get a word pairs with its frequency.
This is my code:

`

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: HdfsWordCount <directory>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HdfsWordCount").setMaster("local")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(12))
    val lines = ssc.textFileStream(args(0))    
    val words2 = lines.map(_.split("[^a-zA-Z]+").filter(str => str.length() >= 5).toList)
    val co_occurrence = words2.flatMap(_.combinations(2)).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

`
I got this output:

(List(quite, search),1)

(List(search, planks),1)

(List(quite, planks),1)

(List(fragile, refused),1)

(List(quite, second),1)

But I expect something like this:

((quite, search),1)

((search, planks),1)

((quite, planks),1)

((fragile, refused),1)

((quite, second),1)

Comment: First of all, your split pattern seems incorrect, you should split by spaces, dots and new lines probably (something like `split("\\s+|\\n+|\\.")`). Also, you should provide some example of what your input looks like, and what your output is.

Comment: Hi, my output is the following:                                                                         
(List(quite, search),1)
(List(search, planks),1)
(List(quite, planks),1)
(List(fragile, refused),1)
(List(quite, second),1)                                                                                                   
But I expect something like this:                                                                             
 ((quite, search),1)
((search, planks),1)
((quite, planks),1)
((fragile, refused),1)
((quite, second),1)

Comment: And your input? How do expect the output to be?

Comment: Well, just wanted to clarify that I have split words correctly so that's not the problem. My problem is that I was expecting the output to be a tupple with first element a tuple of two words and the second element the frequency of that pair of words. In my code I am able to get the occurrence of the pair words succesffuly but the problem is that the firs element is a list of two words instead of a tuple of two words. How can I modify my code so I don't get the list with the two words? For instance I want to get ((quite, search),1) instead of (List(quite, search),1)

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake, I didn't see the `^` at the beginning of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

So as you described your problem in the question comments, what you actually need is to convert a two-elements List into a Tuple of Strings. So we're sure that `combinations(2)` returns a List always consisting of two elements, so we can safely use such function:

```scala
val twoElementsListToTuple: List[String] => (String, String) = {
  case first :: second :: Nil => first -> second
}
```

And then after using the `combinations` method, you can map each of the lists to this function:

```scala
val co_occurrence = words2.flatMap(_.combinations(2).map(twoElementsListToTuple)).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```